# Maximum number of items in DocumentDb IN clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I can't find mention anywhere in the documentation the maximum number of items supported by the IN keyword in DocumentDb.

I would make the assumption that there is a limit.

Can anyone point out in the documentation that is referenced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DocumentDB has virtually eliminated all limits by raising them to a level we don’t foresee our users surpassing, thus they are no longer documented. In this case, 1000 arguments can be in an IN clause.

Comment: good to know, that it's now 1000, because last time when I googled for limitations it was 100.

Comment: for anyone coming back to this post, it appears at the time of writing the limit is now 8000 arguments for an 'IN' query

Answer (score 0):

Currently the limit for AWS DocumentDB is 10K items (10,000) for $in operator:

```
OperationFailure
$in array size must not be greater than 10000
```