# How to select posts of thousand of thousands following users in azure cosmos db?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, cosmos, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I created sample cosmos db using follow link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example

And it is nice work. But I have one big problem. how to select top at least 100 posts of my thousands of thousands following users. I'm thinking many days.
I have million following users. they and their posts are contained within one document. what should I do? and what query to write?

Can you help me please!

Thank you for every one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `how to select top at least 100 posts of my thousands of thousands following users.` Can't understand this. Would you please post more details? what data you want to select? Any tough issues?

Comment: Thank you @JayGong , this sample data (link above) is nice work for small data. I can select top 100 posts using WHERE statement from small data. My problem is select top 100 posts of 100.000 following users or may be million users. I'm thinking WHERE statement is dangerous for RU. I do not know what to do.

Comment: `Top` feature is supported by cosmos db, have you tried it? select top 100 from c where ....

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/

Comment: yes i have tried it. it is no problem. but i don't know for big data. my database is like for this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Comment: @JayGong WHERE userId IN (Val1, Val2 ... ValN). it is nice work. but I think ValN is max 1000. ValN - 1.000.000. is it possible? or should i write any C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Get your concern: `Top` keyword works nice with 1000 items,but is it possible with 100,000 items or more?

Based on the document i shared in the [comment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/), Cosmos DB allocates a fixed amount of time and resources to each query, and when that is reached, returns a continuation token which acts as a bookmark for resuming execution. It's depends on your throughput setting mostly, if the data size is too large, 429 error maybe occur. Please see the http request code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/http-status-codes-for-cosmosdb.

To solve that, DocumentDB supports long running queries via [continuation tokens](https://medium.com/@gary.strange/understanding-cosmosdb-continuation-tokens-hasmoreresults-and-connectionpolicy-requesttimeouts-3ed1fadfa81d).You could set the `maxItemCount` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount?view=azure-dotnet) to paging the result data. If the top keyword need follow some sore rules, like `select top 100 from c where datetime>XXXXX`, it is kind of a little bit complicated. You need to process paging data by code to get the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much, i wrote follow query. "SELECT c.postId, c.userId, n.userId as nID FROM c JOIN n IN c.followers WHERE c.userId IN ('user01', 'user02')". it is nice work. how to use for million following users (user01 ... user1000000)? i want use only one single query. is it possible?

Comment: @batbayar I don't think it's possible because i searched this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376973/maximum-number-of-items-in-documentdb-in-clause, i can't find any further limitation improvement.  I suggest you contacting with azure cosmos team to verify that. But i still recommand you not using such query sql for so large query condition.

Comment: @batbayar The limitation i saw is 8000 now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. what should I do? if you possible, give me some advice.

Comment: @batbayar A,you could verify if the limitation is still 8000 by contacting with azure cosmos db team. B,for me,i would consider using ARRAY_CONTAINS(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) in the sql, please see this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/614.

Comment: @batbayar You could try it and see if it works.Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: I have million following users. they and their posts are contained within one document. what should I do? and what query to write?